# Why isn't my pascals_triangle array not acting as a 2d list and so giving me too many arguments errors?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a function that prints half of pascals triangle(missing the repeated half) so i want each line as a list and append that to the total 2d array called pascals_triangle

```
    Dim line As New List(Of String)
    Dim pascals_triangle As New List(Of List(Of String))
    line.Add(1)
    pascals_triangle.Add(line)
    line.Clear()
    line.Add(1)
    line.Add(1)
    pascals_triangle.Add(line)
    line.Clear()
    Dim row_number As Integer = 0
    Dim row_length As Integer = 1
    For rows = 2 To 40
        For values = 0 To row_length - 1
            If values = row_length - 1 Then
                Dim number = 1
            Else
                Dim number As Integer = pascals_triangle(rows - 1, values) + pascals_triangle(rows, values)
            End If
        Next
        row_length = row_number + 1
    Next
```

Too many arguments for the variable as it doesn't act like a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's *not* a 2D array.  It's an array of arrays.  Which means instead of this syntax:

```
pascals_triangle(1, 1)
```

You'd use this syntax:

```
pascals_triangle(1)(1)
```

The first `1` references the element of the `pascals_triangle` array (well, `List` specifically), and that element is itself an array.  The second `1` indexes *that* array.

The main difference, structurally, between the two is that a 2D array has the same number of positions in every "sub array" and can always be expressed visually as a 2D field, whereas an array of arrays (or jagged array) allows each "sub array" to have its own distinct number of elements.

---

If you want the structure to truly be a 2D array then the declaration might look more like this:

```
Dim pascals_triangle(10, 10) as String
```

Note that this would require also updating much of your code, as you then wouldn't be able to add your `line` list of strings to it, since it's no longer a list of a list of strings.

---

On a side note, your testing can confirm this (and it may be different in C#, which is what I'm used to), but I *suspect* you have a bug here:

```
line.Add(1)
pascals_triangle.Add(line)
line.Clear()
line.Add(1)
line.Add(1)
pascals_triangle.Add(line)
line.Clear()
```

The `line` variable only ever points to the same `List` in memory, and adding it into the `pascals_triangle` object only adds a reference to it.  So any time you call `Clear()` and `Add()` you're calling it on "all" off the "lines", since it's always the same `line` being re-added.

Again, you'll want to confirm this, as I can't say authoritatively if VB has some native way of handling references differently.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind for future projects. :)